# What is the difference between java.lang.Void and void?

Tags: java, void

In API

> "The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a
>   reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void."

1. What is "uninstantiable" place holder class? When will `java.lang.Void` be used? If the class  is "uninstantiable", what use is it?
2. What is difference between `java.lang.Void` and `void`?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The *only point* of `Void` is to hold `Void.TYPE`, which is sort of like `void.class`.  If you have a reflective reference to a method that returns `void`, and you get its return type, it'll return `Void.TYPE`.

You cannot, and should not, use it for anything else.

Comment: Thanks Louis Wasserman.Void.Type can say "primitive type" or any thing

Comment: Wait, what?  That's...not true.  `Void.TYPE` _only_ means `void`.  This isn't C.

Comment: @LouisWasserman `Void` can be used with certain classes that use generics. For example `SwingWorker`. I point this out because you said it cannot be used for anything else.

Comment: That's true; it can substitute generally for a class that's not meant to have any instances except `null`.  But more generally, the `Void` class is just where you go to find `Void.TYPE`, which is like a `Class<void>`.

Comment: I don't think this answer stands up to scrutiny. I've added an example of one area where Void may be used below.

Comment: You also can use Void to create and submit Callable implementations which return void. While using Runnable would probably be prefereable, you may have the submission inside a generic implementation which receives Callables.

Comment: @WillD Or you may need to throw an exception from the `Callable`. Also it's perhaps worth noting that `call` in a `Callable` cannot actually be void, but may have return type `Void` (and thus must return `null`), in order to imitate a void function.

Answer (score 114):

`java.lang.Void` is analogous to [`java.lang.Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html). `Integer` is a way of boxing values of the primitive type `int`. `Void` is a way of boxing values of the primitive type `void`.

"But wait, `void` doesn't have any possible values!"

Right! That's what makes `java.lang.Void` "uninstantiable". :)

It's a nice feature of the Java type system that every primitive type has a boxed equivalent. `int` has `Integer`, `long` has `Long`, `byte` has `Byte`... and `void` has `Void`. It would be weird and asymmetrical if `Void` *didn't* exist.

"So what's the difference between `java.lang.Void` and `void`?"

Easy. `void` is a primitive type. `Void` is an reference type that inherits from `Object`. They're similar in that neither of them has any possible values; but nevertheless they are two very different types, from the type system's point of view.

"But I don't have any use for `Void` in my programs."

And I don't have any use for `GarbageCollectorMXBean` in mine. Some features don't *have* non-obscure uses. That's okay.

Comment: `void` is a keyword but not a `primitive type` actually, `Void.TYPE` is used as a  representation of `void` keyword

Comment: > java.lang.Void is analogous to java.lang.Integer < if that were the case I'd be able to assign Void to a 'void' method. Void is clearly the old one out compared to the other primitive boxings.

Answer (score 77):

**The most common use of `Void` is for reflection, but that is not the only place where it may be used.**

`void` is a keyword that means that a function does not result a value.

`java.lang.Void` is a reference type, then the following is valid:

```
 Void nil = null;
```

(So far it is not interesting...)

As a result type (a function with a return value of type `Void`) it means that the function *always * return `null` (it cannot return anything other than `null`, because `Void` has no instances).

```
 Void function(int a, int b) {
    //do something
    return null;
 }
```

**Why would I like a function that *always* returns null?**

Before the invention of generics, I didn't have a use case for `Void`.

With generics, there are some interesting cases. For instance, a [`Future<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) is a holder for the result of an asynchronous operation performed by another thread. `Future.get` will return the operation value (of type `T`), and will block until the computation is performed.

But... What if there is nothing to return? Simple: use a `Future<Void>`. For instance, in Google App Engine the Asyncronous Datastore Service [`delete`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/AsyncDatastoreService) operation returns a future`. When`get()`is invoked on that future,`null` is returned **after** the deletion is complete. One could write a similar example with [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)s.

Another use case is a `Map` without values, i.e. a `Map<T,Void>`. Such a map behaves like a `Set<T>`, then it may be useful when there is no equivalent implementation of `Set` (for instance, there is no `WeakHashSet`, then one could use a [`WeakHashMap<T,Void>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html)).

Comment: This is a great explanation: essentially, the Void is a way to statically enforce that a type has absolutely no possibility of returning anything at all.  Its much more unambiguous than, for example WeakHashMap<T,Object> , which is what you would have to do otherwise.

Comment: +1 for the examples and insight about using `Map`s containing `Void`s to emulate `Set`s. However, a `WeakHashMap` of `Void`s is not a great example as such a construct would be no better than a plain `HashSet` (no benefit from the 'Weak' functionality). (Interestingly, a `HashSet<E>` is actually backed by a `HashMap<E,Object>`.)

Comment: @Dave, actually they are different, because a `WeakHashMap` has weak references to its keys (while the values are strongly referenced), but a plain `HashSet` keeps strong references to its keys.

Comment: @Javier Yes, you are right. I was mistakenly thinking that the values were weak. My bad.

Answer (score 5):

> Void is a AutoBoxing feature (since JDK 1.5) of void.
>
> well its self explanatory that Void is reference whereas void is a
>   primitive type.
>
> So, where the requirement comes to have to use Void ???
>
> One common usage with Generic types where we can't use primitive.
>
> Say, in case of Android `AsyncTaks<Params, Progress, Result>` what if I
>   don't want to get Progress update. I can't use void (primitive type)
>   here we require java.lang.Void

Comment: JavaDocs mention Void `Since: 1.1`

Answer (score 2):

Another example for using `Void` is `SwingWorker`

```
new SwingWorker<Void, Integer> () {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(){
        ...
    }
    @Override
    protected void process(List<Integer> chunk){
        ...
    }
    @Override
    public void done(){
        ...
    }
}.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Void is useful because sometimes you need to specify the return type of a method outside the method itself.

For example take this [java 8 lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), which checks whether an EventResource object has certain properties, using a method called `checkBenefitConcertInCentralPark`, passed into the method `checkCreatedEvent`:

```
eventChecker.checkCreatedEvent(TestEvents::checkBenefitConcertInCentralPark);
```

The `checkBenefitConcertInCentralPark` method is defined like this (note the use of Void):

```
    public static Void checkBenefitConcertInCentralPark(EventResource eventResource) { 
        // JUnit code here...
        // assertThat(blablabla  :)  )

        return null; // we can only return null at the end of a method when returning Void
    }
```

and then the `checkBenefitConcertInCentralPark` method is passed into the method `checkCreatedEvent`.

```
    // Function<EventResource, Void> describes the checkBenefitConcertInCentralPark method
    public void checkCreatedEvent(Function<EventResource, Void> function) { 
        function.apply(this.eventResource);
    }
```

Comment: You don't explain why you'd need a Function returning Void instead of just using a Consumer.

Answer (score 0):

I've personally used it like this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface MyPackagePrivateInterface<T, Next> {
   //Returns next
   Next compareAndSwap(T prev);
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface ClientPublicInterface<T> extends MyPackagePrivateInterface<T, Void> {
}
```

My reasoning is this:

computations based on user input, may create new Type allocations, that your system may need.

The action may KEEP its namesake since in the eyes of the client it is performing what it is saying, but in sublayers within the system an equivalent action is taking place but with completely different Types, Types which ONLY your system should be aware.

This may relate to a principle of "Self similarity" in which a system is composed of smaller components similar to itself, so it may be logical to reuse interfaces with different Types and similar namesake, this system also implies that reification (transforming something abstract into real) is intrinsical to the System state hence the user is not interested in an immediate reading of a return value, but the aim relies on the Object's change of state.

Now this particular example is for atomic operations, and TBH I cannot think of a different situation in which this may be needed, the reason being that native atomic operations are reliant in time-space(space = memory scope) snapshots for them to perform accurately.

This new allocations are not important to the client but only to the system's functionality.