# Setting generic types of SwingWorker as void?

Tags: java, swing, generics, void, swingworker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between java.lang.Void and void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839042/what-is-the-difference-between-java-lang-void-and-void)

I wanted to create a concrete class for `SwingWorker` with both final and intermediate result types as `void`. I wrote the following code:

```
class AnswerWorker extends SwingWorker<void, void> {
    protected void doInBackGround() {
        System.out.println("what is your problem!!");
    }
}
```

This gave me the following error:

```
Multiple markers at this line-
    Syntax error on token "void", Dimensions expected after this token.
    Syntax error on token "void", Dimensions expected after this token.
```

However when i changed the code from `void` to `Void` (i.e. small `v` to capital `V`), it worked fine, although I was still forced to `return null;` at the end of `doInBackground()` method.

Why is this? I know `Void` is a class in `java.lang` package but the documentation doesn't says much about it (atleast not which i could follow :p)

Thanx in advance!!

Comment: and important could be two parameters, are there really <void, void>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`class AnswerWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>`
Should do the trick. 
That is because generics always need objects as parameters. They also can't take primitives. [Void](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) is like a Wrapper to get rid of this issue.

Now the cause why you still need to return something:
As the documentation says, `Void` is still a class. So you need still to return an object. Since it's uninstantiable, there's only the possibility of returning `null`.  So `Void` isn't fully like the `void` keyword. There's still the need to return a reference to an object (null-reference in this case).

There's one important thing: **Generics force you to use objects.** `void`, like primitive types, isn`t an object. That's the pure oop nature of Java ;)

Answer (score 3):

The `java.lang.Void` class was originally introduced long before generics as a place to put the constant `Void.TYPE`, the `Class` object that represents the `void` type, and which is returned by `java.lang.reflect.Method.getReturnType()` for `void` methods (by analogy to `Integer.TYPE`, `Character.TYPE`, etc. which represent `int`, `char`, ...).

The `Void` class can't be instantiated (therefore the only valid value you can assign to a variable of type `Void` is `null`) but it has been co-opted since the introduction of generics as a useful token for situations like this where the syntax requires a class name but you don't really want to use one.

Comment: Could you point me to some official/authoritative documentation to confirm this sentence in the context of `SwingWorker`?: _it has been co-opted since the introduction of generics as a useful token for situations like this where the syntax requires a class name but you don't really want to use one_.

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel I can't, I chose the term "co-opted" to imply that it's an unofficial convention rather than an official recommendation.  If you're always going to return `null` then it doesn't really matter what class you use, but `Void` is a useful convention.  The same convention is used by [`java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveAction.html), it's a "resultless" `ForkJoinTask` that always returns `null`, so it extends `ForkJoinTask<Void>`.

Comment: the fact that there is a class in the standard Java API using `Void` like that seems quite official reference to me. Thanks!.