# java.lang.Void vs void vs Null

Tags: java, android, null, void

What exactly is the difference between `Void`, `void`, and can I just use `null` instead?

I'm asking this is because I'm looking at sample Android code where they used Void but Eclipse errors on it (it says `Void cannot be resolved to a variable`).

My code that breaks is

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{
    ...
}
```

I use it like this

```
MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask();
myAsyncTask.execute((Void),null);//this is the line that breaks  "Void cannot be resolved to a variable"
```

Comment: It'd help if we could see the code that was breaking.

Comment: im going to add a small snippet. just cleaning it up

Comment: by the way you can also try myAsyncTask.execute(new Void[1]);
=D

Comment: There is no Null type.

Comment: @shmosel Fair, but while technically incorrect it is what the question was about so I believe it is the correct title, that's why I approved the edit but changed the title back to the original `Null`

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839042/what-is-the-difference-between-java-lang-void-and-void

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra comma in your code.

```
myAsyncTask.execute((Void),null);
                        //^extra comma right here
```

Also, there is no need to cast `null` to `Void`, because (1) `Void` has no instances and thus there is no `Void` object, and (2) casting `null` to anything is rather useless because null is a valid value for any Object data type.

Code should probably just be:

```
myAsyncTask.execute(null);
```

Comment: it was the extra comma Thanks! i didnt realize its a cast (i thought its two args) but for some reason it does have to be casted otherwise it errors out saying `execute(void[]) is ambiguous for the type MyAsyncTask`

Comment: The safest bet in this case is actually `myAsyncTask.execute();`

Answer (score 61):

**The most common use of `Void` is for reflection, but that is not the only place where it may be used.**

`void` is a keyword that means that a function does not result a value.

`java.lang.Void` is a reference type, then the following is valid:

```
 Void nil = null;
```

(so far it is not interesting...)

As a result type (a function with a return value of type `Void`) it means that the function *always * return `null` (it cannot return anything other than `null`, because `Void` has no instances).

```
 Void function(int a, int b) {
    //do something
    return null;
 }
```

**Why would I like a function that *always* returns null?**

Before the invention of generics, I didn't have an use case for `Void`.

With generics, there are some interesting cases. For instance, a [`Future<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) is a holder for the result of an asynchronous operation performed by other thread. `Future.get` will return the operation value (of type `T`), and will block until the computation is performed.

But... what if there is nothing to return? Simple: use a `Future<Void>`. For instance, in Google App Engine the Asyncronous Datastore Service [`delete`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/AsyncDatastoreService) operation returns a `Future<Void>`. When `get()` is invoked on that future, `null` is returned **after** the deletion is complete. One could write a similar example with [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)s.

Another use case is a `Map` without values, i.e. a `Map<T,Void>`. Such a map behaves like a `Set<T>`, then it may be useful when there is no equivalent implementation of `Set` (for instance, there is no `WeakHashSet`, then one could use a [`WeakHashMap<T,Void>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html)).

Answer (score 4):

`Void` is "an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void." (from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html)

`void` is a return type signifying no return.

`null` is the absence of value.

Answer (score 2):

`java.lang.Void` is the boxed representation of the `void` type.  Since you can't have an instance of type `void`, it's mostly there for completeness and the very rare instance where you need it for reflection.

Comment: `java.lang.Void` is *not* the [boxed representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_(object-oriented_programming)#Boxing) of `void`. Calling it a boxed representation implies that you're wrapping a primitive. `void` is not a primitive, nor is it even a type, and there is no wrapping occurring.

Comment: Some resources, such as http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Programming/java/miscellaneous_java/Java_Primitive_Types.html, cite `void` as being a primitive type.  It's certainly not a class.  It's entire purpose is to stand in for the primitive type of equivalent purpose, which is what "boxed representations" actually do.

Comment: The [Java Langauge Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8) states that `void` is not a type.

Comment: it's interesting. since when i look at the code for class `Void` i see   
`public static final Class<Void> TYPE = (Class<Void>) Class.getPrimitiveClass("void");`
 which kinds of showing that void is considered as primitive type.

Answer (score 1):

`void` : java keyword indicates method will not return anything. Used for methods

`Void` : Wrapper around void. It extends Object class.

Needed as Generic does not support primitive datatypes. 
(void considered primitive is a complex case but this is just to explain)

Should be used for reflection

```
Constructor<Void> constructor = Void.class.getConstructor()
```

`null` indicates no values. Used for objects as comparison to void which is used for methods.