# Android - openConnection giving error

Tags: android, android-networking

I have tried as much as I could yet my code maintains errors. I am simply trying to do a POST method in an android app. I do realize in the code below you will find void with capital "v" this is because the error wasn't going till I made it as Void

```
public class PostMethod extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Void> {


    protected Void doInBackground(URL... url) {


        try {

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes("Hello! ");
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error! ");
        }


    }

}
```

This code is placed in my on create function.

```
try {
    new PostMethod().execute(new URL("http://posttestserver.com/data/"));
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Current error: It cannot identify openConnection()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url[0].openConnection();
```

instead of

```
 HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

beacuse `doInBackground` parameter is [Varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) method argument

Comment: Works perfectly but why is the void with a capital "v" that isn't correct right?

Comment: @user3329118 : `Void` is return type of doInBackground method which must be same as you are passing in `AsyncTask<URL, Void, Void>` as last argument.

Comment: I am having an error saying it expects me to return a value. But void doesn't return any value?

Comment: @user3329118: yes `return null` from `doInBackground`

Comment: @user3329118 : for more information see [What is the difference between java.lang.Void and void?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839042/what-is-the-difference-between-java-lang-void-and-void)

Comment: Thanks just one last question, I am getting an error android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. I have a do in background method , why is it breaking?

Comment: @user3329118 : in which line you are getting error? also always use @override before method if you are overriding from superclass. so add @Override before `doInBackground`

Comment: I did do that sadly, I still have the same error. I will try to pin point which line it is in