# Java typical usage of Void autoboxing type

Tags: java

What is the practical usage of Void reference type in java? How can it help me in practical programming?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839042/what-is-the-difference-between-java-lang-void-and-void

Comment: `java.lang.Void` is not an autoboxing type

Answer (score 2):

It is useful where you need to return some object type (e.g. if the return type is generic), but "return nothing" is the natural thing to do, e.g.

```
class MyCallable implements Callable<Void> {
  @Override public Void call() {
    // ... whatever
    return null;
  }
}
```